# Can I change the playback speed of a sound in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio, flash-cs5

I have a sound clip in flash that lasts 10 seconds. I'd like to play it back in a shorter time, and at a higher pitch.

How can I do this in ActionScript 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by extracting part of the Sound as a ByteArray, then manipulating and playing it in a new Sound object.

Here is a [nice example](http://www.kelvinluck.com/2008/11/first-steps-with-flash-10-audio-programming/) of how to do it.